# jQuery jPlayer - enable download for client?

Tags: jquery, html5-audio, jplayer

I am looking to enable functionality (i.e. a button) for the client to download the sound file through jplayer.  I have already looked briefly in the Developer's guide and Google group for this functionality without success.

If it is of any help, here is my code for it:

```
<div id="jquery_jplayer_1" class="jp-jplayer"></div>
<div id="jp_container_1" class="jp-audio">
    <div class="jp-type-single">
        <div class="jp-gui jp-interface">
            <ul class="jp-controls">
                <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-play" tabindex="1">play</a></li>
                <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-pause" tabindex="1">pause</a></li>
                <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-stop" tabindex="1">stop</a></li>
                <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-mute" tabindex="1" title="mute">mute</a></li>
                <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-unmute" tabindex="1" title="unmute">unmute</a></li>
                <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-volume-max" tabindex="1" title="max volume">max volume</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="jp-progress">
                <div class="jp-seek-bar">
                    <div class="jp-play-bar"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="jp-volume-bar">
                <div class="jp-volume-bar-value"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="jp-time-holder">
                <div class="jp-current-time"></div>
                <div class="jp-duration"></div>
                <ul class="jp-toggles">
                    <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-repeat" tabindex="1" title="repeat">repeat</a></li>
                    <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-repeat-off" tabindex="1" title="repeat off">repeat off</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="jp-title">
            <ul>
                <li>Voice Recording</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="jp-no-solution">
            <span>Update Required</span>
            To play the media you will need to either update your browser to a recent version or update your <a href="http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/" target="_blank">Flash plugin</a>.
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am using jplayer on my website, and I just use a link with a PHP function to download the file. Is there a reason you want to use the jplayer?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the "jPlayer Playlist Add-on". See the section "Defining Playlist Content" for info how to set the `free` property for a track (which automatically generates links allowing it to be downloaded).

http://www.jplayer.org/latest/demo-02-jPlayerPlaylist/

> The second parameter is an Array of Objects used to define the
>   playlist. The object elements are used by the jPlayer setMedia
>   command, so follow the rules for suppling the formats defined in the
>   supplied option. The title, artist and free properties are used by
>   jPlayerPlaylist to display each item. To start with an empty playlist,
>   use an empty array, []. A playlist with a single audio item looks
>   like:

```
[
  {
    title:"The Title",
    artist:"The Artist", // Optional
    free: Boolean, // Optional - Generates links to the media
    mp3:"MP3 URL", // Dependant on supplied option
    oga:"OGA URL", // Dependant on supplied option
    poster: "Poster URL" // Optional
  }
]
```